# How to attach character to the next N lines using Emacs?

Tags: emacs, emacs24

Using `emacs24` I'd like to attach for example `#` at the beginning of the next five lines.
So having this:

```
Line1
line2
line3
```

get this:

```
#Line1
#line2
#line3
```

for the number of lines that I specify. How can I do that? Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like `comment-region`?

Comment: @vonbrand Yes! .. thats the example and That would help me, but i also would like to know how to make the logic for that...

Comment: FWIW, with `M-;` bound to `comment-dwim`, this sort of commenting requirement is generally taken care of.

Comment: See also this question over at the Emacs stackexchange site: http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/11/how-to-add-a-prefix-to-every-line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there may be something built in to Emacs that does this, and you can certainly write a little Lisp to get it done, I would usually use "rectangular editing" features to get this done. Imagine that the buffer contains the following, with `.` representing the point (where your cursor is)

```
.Line1
line2
line3
```

Set the mark

Press `C-n` twice. This is the state of the buffer now:

```
Line1
line2
.line3
```

Press `C-x r t`.

Type `#`.

Press enter.

I would find this much more natural than entering a value for the number of times to repeat a command, because you can visually select the lines you want to edit. YMMV

*Edit*

Here's how to do this using a bit of Emacs Lisp. Note that although I've been using Emacs for a few years now, I only recently began learning how to actually use Emacs Lisp, so this code might not be that great! It does get the job done.

```
(defun insert-n-times (s n)
  (interactive "Mstring:\nNtimes:")
  (while (> n 0)
    (insert s)
    (goto-char (- (point) 1))
    (next-line)
    (setq n (- n 1))))
```

Use it by doing the following: `M-x insert-n-times RET <type a string> RET <type a number>`

Comment: Suggestion: You might want to use `(move-beginning-of-line 2)` to go to the beginning of the next line. Also, `(setq n (- n 1))` you can write as `(decf n)`. Just some, as I see it, nice shortcuts!

Comment: @spacemanaki thank you a lot. I like the natural way you propose. It's easier to make. For the `Emacs Lisp` method: It's also really great, I'm not sure of how to use it.. I'm a begginer with Emacs.. where do I have to define the lisp? or how should I create it?

Comment: A good way to start playing with Emacs Lisp is to use the `*scratch*` buffer: switch to it with `C-x b`, `C-s...` and then copy and paste the Lisp code into the buffer. You can then do `M-x eval-buffer` to evaluate the whole buffer. Alternatively, put your point (cursor) immediately after the last close paren and type `C-x C-e`.

Answer (score 2):

Another method is using macro to get such repetitive work done. [Here](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/KeyboardMacros) is a page that describes how to use macros in Emacs. You can have a look at it if you are not familiar with it.

In your case, the following keys would work:

1. Move the cursor to the beginning of Line1
2. C-x (
3. Type a '#'
4. C-n, then C-a
5. C-x )
6. Move the cursor to the line to the beginning of which you want to add '#'
7. C-u 10 C-x e

Basically, step 2-5 will record a macro which will add a # at the beginning, and then move to the beginning of the next line. Step 6-7 will execute the macro 10 times (of course, you can change it to arbitrary number). I guess this will be quite a lot of keystrokes and newbies may not like it. Maybe others have better solutions.

Comment: If you want to make this look "easier" replace `C-x (` with F3, `C-x )` with F4 and step 7 also F4.

Comment: thank you a lot! .. a quick way to create a repetitive instruction! And the @Dualinity suggestion makes this a great combination. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Line1
line2
line3
```

I wrote the following code:

- You first give a digit argument (the amount of times you want to do this), e.g. `M-3` (hold alt, hit 3), to do the following 3 times
- Either use a key for it, like a suggestion below (f8), or use M-x `prompt-for-insert`
- It will ask you for a string to enter. e.g. "foo" and hit return button.

It will then do as you ask.

```
(defun prompt-for-insert (val)
  (interactive "P")
  (let ((astring (read-string "What do you want to insert?"))
        (value val))
    (while (> value 0)
      (insert astring)
      (move-beginning-of-line 2)
      (decf value)))
  )

(global-set-key [f8] 'prompt-for-insert)
```

The whole sequence will then be:

```
M-3 [f8] foo RET
```

Resulting in:

```
fooLine1
fooline2
fooline3
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just `query-replace-regexp` or `replace-regexp`?  E.g. select the region and do <kbd>C-M-%</kbd><kbd>^</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>#</kbd><kbd>RET</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Try `M-x string-insert-rectangle`. This command inserts a string on every line of the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

While `comment-region` is good in this specific example, check out the `multiple-cursors` package for a very powerful way to do this kind of thing in general.

You can just hit `C->` repeatedly until you have a cursor at the beginning of each line, then hit `#` and you're done (`C-g` to get rid of the extra cursors.)

It's a much more interactive form of `C-x r t` and works with non-rectangular regions too (after a `C-s` for example.)